# Undo is "done" or "undone"?

Tags: copywriting, actions, undo

**After you click "undo"** the action is either completed immediately or you see the percentage that shows the progress.

I'm interested in the second case.

As it might take some time to complete this action. That is why in our interface there would be a percentage showing the progress of this action. Which word to better use after this percentage?

**Example:**

**23% done**

**23% undone**

---

**Done or undone?**

Comment: I think this question belongs on https://english.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: How about "23% complete"?

Answer (score 3):

Could you visually differentiate the action from the status? For example, after clicking “Undo”, you could display a modal or message that includes the action title (e.g. “Undo *Action Name*” - which confirms the chosen action) and a progress bar or percentage number showing the progress/estimated time to completion (“23% complete”).

Answer (score 2):

Would you be able to use other words to better describe the action?

Example, "Installing" vs "Uninstalling", the words are very clear on what the program is doing.

Maybe you can try "Aborting", "Cancelling"...maybe "Undoing" the present participle of "Undo" which I think might be a better fit than the past participle "Undone".

Answer (score 2):

Reverting changes: 23%

*This is totally more of a language issue than a UX issue btw.*

Answer (score 1):

You could try "x% Undoing Something" or even "x% done undoing" (ok the last one seems like it will confuse a lot of people)

But then again since undoing is a **process**, it will make sense that you use "x% done", since it's finishing the process that the user started. I'm quite certain users will also understand if you used "undoing", since they get it that they clicked on the "undo" button and that the app is currently "undoing the what they recently did".